# Square sequence puzzle

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence, sequence

Find what comes next in the following sequence.

> 01, 04, 09, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 00, 21, 44, 69, 96, 25, ?

Bonus: What is the rule of the sequence?

Comment: this one was a little too easy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

f(n) = (n^2) % 100

so next is f(16) = 256 % 100 = 56

Comment: I guess you're using % to mean modulo here?

Comment: Yes, '%' means modulo

Answer (score 0):

**The next number is-**

> 56

**The rule is-**

> The $n^{th}$ term is squared and then, divided by $100$. Then, the remainder obtained is the next number in the sequence. 
> $\therefore$ $16^{th}$ term = $16^2$ = $256$
> Now, dividing it by $100$, we get the remainder 56.